# Get Packages composer.json Values Within Laravel Command Class

Tags: node.js, laravel, gruntjs, vagrant, composer-php

I would like to be able to set some configuration values within a particular package that I'm developing for laravel.

example:

```
"extra": {
    "maxminddbpath": "src/storage/db"
},
```

I need to access those values from within one of my classes. How can this be accomplished.

Pseudocode might look something like this:

```
public function fire()
{
      $this->getCompiler()->getPackage()->getExtra();//returns the extra node from composer.json
}
```

For my example I will be accessing the value from within a class that extends \Command

---

I would tend to agree that in some eyes this is something fanatical or silly because there is a better option. I understand that

In that case could you answer this, are there any instances where one might find it better as a software architect to locate provisional static values within that configuration file(composer.json)?

I think what is happening is we are avoiding the question by stating that it shouldn't be done.

an argument could then be made that the configuration of a json file is irrelevant to that of the application, which; by the nature the composer.json configuration file could not be true.

---

Take a look at this line of code on github:
https://github.com/mente/MaxMindGeoIpBundle/blob/master/Composer/ScriptHandler.php#L22

This was designed for symphony and not laravel but they are parent child branches of each other. I assume that there would be something within the laravel framework to handle this type of request.

---

**Other uses might include:**

- Reading Grunt Files
- Reading Ruby Configuration
- Reading Node Configuration
- Reading Deployment Settings
- Reading Vagrant Configurations

**Recommendations for a library?.**

Comment: Are you developing this package for public distribution? (If so, this probably isn't a good idea.)

Comment: Why don't you use a Laravel configuration file for that?

Comment: It's possible that it would be used for public distribution, not in the plans currently. Please explain why this wouldn't be a good idea? These values are more like constants that configuration pieces; so I want them within the composer.json instead of the configuration file. What is the difference(non obvious)?

This is what I'm modeling the package after: https://github.com/mente/MaxMindGeoIpBundle

Comment: @ajameswolf I have never used composer.json for config/constants...

Answer (score 1):

Configuration in `composer.json` should only be configuration which is used during a composer process. In such cases, you have to use composer scripts, which have access to this extras config.

When a setting is not specifically used in a composer process, it's more part of the app configuration and should belong in the configuration file of the application. I don't know Laravel well, but I guess it has nice configuration features.

Comment: I agree, laravel does have a nice configuration feature and it is nice and easy to add a file and return an array to a package. That is an option that I use regularly. I'm looking for a way to read these values through laravel.